# Generate some random matrix with given rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random, matrix-calculus

Very often for creating new exercises (I teach basic matrix algebra), I need to a find a matrix $A$ such that:

- it has integer coefficients, not too big (in order to avoid big numbers computations)
- it has a given format (ex : (3,4) ), has a given rank  (ex : 2)
- the computations in order to perform a row echelon form are not **too** complicated...

**Do you know how I can easily generate such matrix (online tool?)**

*Of course I could do a Maple or Python program to do that, but I wanted to know if such a ready-to-use tool already exists.*

Comment: I'm not aware of any "nice matrix generator". It would certainly be a useful tool :)

Answer (score 2):

Parts $1$ and $2$ are very easy:

If you want an $m \times n$ rank $r$ matrix, then compute $UPV$ where

- $U$ is $m \times m$ invertible
- $V$ is $n \times n$ invertible and
- $P$ the $m \times n$ matrix that looks like
  $$P = \begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$
  with $r$ ones.

If you generate $U$ and $V$ at random, they are highly likely to be invertible.

Part 3 is a bit tricky, because what makes echelon computations hard is a bit subjective. I would start with the matrix in row echelon form and apply a small number of random row operations.

Comment: I think OP is looking for a ready to use tool, not instructions on how to generate such a matrix.  Given what he or she is teaching I'd expect him or her to know that already.

Comment: It takes about a moment to convert the first answer into a tool: `Table[Random[], {m}, {m}].Table[If[p == q && p <= r, 1, 0], {p, m}, {q, n}].Table[Random[], {n}, {n}]` in Mathematica, for example. A few more moments to the other one.

Comment: Thanks for this (@JPi you're right, I already know this, if not I couldn't teach matrix algebra ;) ), I will try to use it in Maple as well (or is there an online Mathematica interpreter ?) 

The only problem with this method is that the coefficients won't be in a small interval (having all coefficients in $[-5..5]$ would be great for students in order to have simple computations)

Comment: @Basj When I was teaching linear algebra, I was simply using a similar approach with a criterion that the RREF forms had to be "nice" in the sense that there were no fractions etc. This can be easily checked in MATLAB, Octave or whatever tool you use. You just need essentially to generate some "nice" matrices in a loop and stop it when the form you want to compute from it (RREF, QR, etc.) is nice enough.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer does this approach span the set of such matrices? I.e., if we multiplied _all_ invertible $m\times m$ $U$ and _all_ invertible $n \times n$ $V$, would we have _all_ $m\times n$ rank $r$ matrices? (my instincts say yes, but my linear algebra is too rusty to say with confidence)